# NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES

Tags: asp.net, html, w3c-validation

Trying to get close a W3C validation of the output from my aspx (VB.NET 2008 Framework 3)
I get this warning:

> Warning Line 6, Column 76: NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG
>   YES

```
</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

> The sequence  can be interpreted in at least two different
>   ways, depending on the DOCTYPE of the document. For HTML 4.01 Strict,
>   the '/' terminates the tag '). However, since
>   many browsers don't interpret it this way, even in the presence of an
>   HTML 4.01 Strict DOCTYPE, it is best to avoid it completely in pure
>   HTML documents and reserve its use solely for those written in XHTML.

**But**... in my source editor from visual I can see this:

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

And after loading the page, and viewing the source code in Firefox, I can see this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Why can be happens this?

Thanks

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET will vary the output by user agent. You can try some of the ideas presented in [Making asp.net 2.0 play nice with the W3C validator](http://idunno.org/archive/2005/08/01/216.aspx) and see if they work for you.

Comment: Link is dead I guess!