# HTML without “self-closing” tags

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

There's some way to cut the html tags with self-closing slash like `<br/>` and transform it to `<br>` so you can view on the source view the code without the slash?

Some DOM Jquery implementation?

I'm working on .NET if this can be help as a tip.

This is the real problem: [NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503690/net-enabling-start-tag-requires-shorttag-yes)

Comment: Unless you explain in reasonable why you want to do this you're not going to get many, if any, answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503690/net-enabling-start-tag-requires-shorttag-yes That's my real problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your other question, DaveB's answer points to a browser capabilities file. In that file the `tagWriter` is set to`System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter`.

I haven't tested this, but you may be able to sub-class `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter` and initialse the value of the `SelfClosingTagEnd` field so that its value is `>` instead of `/>`.

Put the name of the new class in the `tagWriter` setting of your browser capabilities file and try that.